# Why won't Ghostscript recognize my modified 'cidfmap' file?

Tags: ghostscript

I'm attempting to use Ghostscript 9.27 on Windows 10 Pro to compress a PDF with CID fonts, using a modified 'cidfmap' file ($GS_HOME/Resource/Init/cidfmap). However, Ghostscript doesn't seem to recognize my changes to 'cidfmap', and instead wants to load the DroidSansFallback TrueType font to emulate the missing CID font.

I have tried using the "-I" command line parameter to tell Ghostscript to use the modified file in the $GS_HOME/Resource/Init directory, as specified in the documentation.

I've also tried building the source code within Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, using the following command (and no errors):

```
nmake /A psi/msvc.mak MSVC_VERSION=15 WIN64=
```

Below is the full Ghostscript command I am running in the command prompt:

```
gswin64c.exe -I"C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/Init" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dPDFSTOPONERROR -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=output.pdf m0001-062-1.pdf
```

the record added to the 'cidfmap' file (it's the only one):

```
/MSPGothic << /FileType /TrueType /Path ("C:/Windows/Fonts/msgothic.ttc") /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Japan1) 2] >> ;
```

and the output from Ghostscript I've been receiving in both cases:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.27 (2019-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 4.
Page 1
Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold... 4570288 3226611 4074256 2336262 4 done.
Page 2
Page 3
Querying operating system for font files...
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 5086792 3742157 2284000 967988 4 done.
Substituting font Helvetica-Narrow for ArialNarrow.
Loading NimbusSansNarrow-Regular font from C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/Font/NimbusSansNarrow-Regular... 5273304 3930300 2397536 1064531 4 done.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Loading NimbusSans-Bold font from C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold... 5500440 4150230 3021540 1680111 4 done.
Can't find CID font "MSPGothic".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Japan1 for /MSPGothic, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Japan1" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Japan1 ... Done.
Page 4
Can't find CID font "MSPGothic".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Japan1 for /MSPGothic, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from C:/Program Files/gs/ghostscript-9.27/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Japan1 ... Done.
```

It seems as if I've missed something simple here, as others with similar questions got it working with just the "-I" command line parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't tell without seeing the original PDF file, its possible there's something unusual about the CIDFont name, or info. It could be the Registry information for the CIDfont. If you post the original file somewhere and supply the URL here I'll take a look.

Comment: Ken, thanks for your response! I've provided a link for you to test the PDF file on your end: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JGaK7dOp7Bvmo2wNlKvYWLtQXhPW_16R It is not the original (for security reasons), but it does generate similar output to the above when run through Ghostscript. Let me know if you absolutely need the original, and I can send it to you via your work e-mail.

Comment: No need for the original, as long as it produces the same problem that's good enough, I'll grab it now and experiment

Comment: D'oh, the problem was obvious, I've made it an asnwer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is (once I looked carefully enough!) clear. You've put quotes "" around the filename.

The '(' and ')' characters are string delimiters in PostScript, not " (and the cidfmap file is read as a PostScript program) so by doing that you've made the " characters part of the path. Unsurprisingly Ghostscript can't find a path beginning with "

So if you change your cidfmap entry to:

```
/MSPGothic << /FileType /TrueType /Path (C:/Windows/Fonts/msgothic.ttc) /SubfontID 0 /CSI [(Japan1) 2] >> ;
```

you should find it works, it does for me.

Comment: Yep, that was it! I was trying to keep the command line option paths in quotes, and so I mistakenly thought the quotes were needed here as well. Thanks so much for your help, Ken!